# UrlConnection timeout not working

Tags: java, http

I am using UrlConnection for accessing my local webserver.
I measure the time it takes for each requests and some requests take up to 200.000ms.

How can this be, even if i configured timeouts?

I tested on Windows 7 64 bit (Java 7 64 bit) & Debian 7 64 bit (Java 7 64 bit)

Yes, i read the related questions / answers on SO, but they could not solve the issue.

```
public String download(String link) throws IOException {
            URL url = null;
            String html;
            url = new URL(link);

            resource = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(Proxy.NO_PROXY);

            resource.setConnectTimeout(2500);
            resource.setReadTimeout(4500);
            resource.addRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            resource.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Analyzer");

            resource.setRequestMethod("GET");
            resource.connect();
            if(resource.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            is = resource.getInputStream();

            String charset = resource.getContentEncoding();
            if (charset == null)
                    charset = getCharset(resource.getContentType());

            html =  inputStreamToString(is, charset);
            } else {
                    html = null;
            }
            //System.out.println(link+" => "+resource.getResponseCode());
            resource.disconnect();
            if(is != null) {
                    is.close();
            }
            return html;
    }
```